# Is there a way to use ASP.Net Memberships to grant permissions dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

Suppose for a social network-ish project you have an if-statement such as:

`if (currentMember.IsFriendsWith(otherMember)....`

How would you go about granting permission for the current user to only have persmission to see `otherMember's`  profile if the method returned a true value?

Comment: Obviously your membership user is related to another user via relation table `user_friends`. So you could write a method that checks this by passing two user-ids(or extending your custom membership provider class). It is not(does not necessarily need to be) part of the ASP.NET authentication process.

Comment: This is a design problem. It will also dictate how you want to store permissions.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Membership provider to implement your business logic of friendship relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. To put it this way: Why can't you just use the actual `if`-statement in your question when attempting to fetch and / or display the profile of `OtherMember`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be simpler to add a `public IQueriable<GUID> FriendsUserKey { get; set; }` to the user's profile model. This way you could just see if the `FriendsUserKey` contains another user's key, if so then they are a friend.

Then you can write a method to work the way you want, `currentMember.IsFriendsWith(otherMember)`

Be careful not to base this off the `UserName` in case a user is deleted and later a new user uses the same `UserName`.

To answer your title, "Is there a way to use ASP.Net Memberships to grant permissions dynamically?" Yes there is in the sense that you can add and create roles dynamically, however this wouldn't be the way to go for this situation.

To create a role, `Roles.CreateRole("roleName");` and to add a user to this role, `Roles.AddUserToRoles("userName", "roleNames");`